# Print a specific part in an output

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Let us suppose that there is a command such as:

```
cat /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic | grep CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG
```

The output is as such:

```
CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig"
```

Now, my question is: Are there any commands which will only print what is inside the inverted commas, i.e., `" "`?

And could you please explain the command a little? Thank you! in advance.

Comment: Note that using `cat` in a pipe is almost always a waste of resources (AKA [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)); `grep` can read its input from a file already (i.e. `grep CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic` does exactly the same thing, but 1. It's shorter 2. It's easier to understand 3. It doesn't fork an additional shell and an additional process). In 99% of the cases, using cat at the start of the pipe without concatenating multiple files it's just harmful. :)

Comment: @kos - Thanx! Didn't know that as I have just started using linux. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: Np! I'm leaving my comment above for other people stumbling across this question.

Comment: The initial `cat`, though useless in this case, would make editing the entire line of commands easier in the future in case you want to change / add / remove something later, maybe a `tr` or `cut`, etc, don't have to find & move the filename, make sure the other command supports it, find where to put it, etc. And for a small test file it only adds 0.002s. *(I've probably spent more time typing this than I'll ever save in a lifetime of avoiding superfluous `cat`'s)*

Comment: @Xen2050 why does the `cat` help here? You can do `grep foo file | tr` or `... | cut` just as easily as `cat file | tr | grep ...`. The `cat` just adds an extra five characters, an extra pipe and an extra program call and doesn't simplify anything.

Comment: @kos The (somewhat pedantic) complaint about using `cat` at the start of a pipeline is correct, but the replacement you give does not support your argument in general, only for the specific case of `grep`. Not all pipeline programs accept an explicit file name instead of the standard input, and if they do they may treat the two cases differently. The systematic way to avoid pipes that start with a `cat` invocation is to use _input redirection_ instead; this creates the exact same situation (notably the shell opens the file). So here that would be `</boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic grep  ...`.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen "Only for the specific case of `grep`": not at all. By all odds 99% of the GNU tools (just to speak about those) will support passing a filename as an argument (the only exception that I can remember of being `tr`). And if we're making points that "not always...", then a program might as well just ignore STDIN, so technically shell redirection can't be a "systematic way to avoid pipes" either. Nevertheless passing a filename is to be preferred to a redirection when possible, since using redirection will prevent the tool to seek through the file, which usually speeds things up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  Your command would be:

```
cat /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic | grep CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

which would return only:

```
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
```

The `awk` command uses field separators with the `-F` command, and to set it to use double-quotes, you type it in with single-quotes around it like `-F'"'`.  Then the `'{print $2}'` tells awk to print the second set after the field separator.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Terrance, In this case this is a useless use of `cat` and `grep`. You could replace `cat` and `grep` part with `awk -F'"' '/CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG/{print $2}' /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic`  . Less plumbing , letting AWK do all the work, which it is more than capable of doing

Comment: Agree with @Serg

Comment: @Serg No problems.  I understand what you're saying.  I was only adding on to his original command by adding on the `awk` command.  =)

Answer (score 11):

You can do that with a single `grep` command:

```
grep -Po '^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="\K[^"]*' /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic
```

Or (a bit longer and more convulted):

```
grep -Po '^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="\K.*?(?=")' /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic
```

- `-P`: tells `grep` to interpret the pattern as a PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression);
- `-o`: tells `grep` to print only the match;
- `^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="`: matches a `CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="` string at the start of the line;
- `\K`: discards the previously matched substring;

#1:

- `[^"]*`: matches any number of any character not `"` (greedily).

#2:

- `.*?`: matches any number of any character (lazily);
- `(?=")`: lookahead (zero-lenght assertion, it doesn't match any character); matches if the following character is a `"`.

```
% grep -Po '^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="\K[^"]*' /boot/config-4.2.0-16-generic
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
% grep -Po '^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="\K.*?(?=")' /boot/config-4.2.0-16-generic
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
```

Comment: I love learning more than one way to achieve the same results.  Great answer!  =)

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to skin this cat, here is a `sed` way:

```
sed -nr 's/^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="([^"]+)"$/\1/p' /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic
```

Here we are matching the line and capturing the desired portion i.e. the portion within double quotes (`([^"]+)`) and then replacing the whole line with the captured group (`\1`) only.

**Example:**

```
% sed -nr 's/^CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="([^"]+)"$/\1/p' /boot/config-3.13.0-32-generic
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
```

Answer (score 10):

What, no `perl`?

```
grep CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic | 
    perl -pe 's/.*?"([^"]*).*/$1/'
```

The `perl` will `-p`rint every line after applying the script given by `-e`. The `s/foo/bar/` will substitute `foo` with `bar`. Patterns in parentheses are "captured" and can be referred to as `$1`, `$2` ... `$N` where `$1` is the 1st pattern captured, `$2` the second etc. The regular expression will look for everything until the first quote (`.*?"`), then capture 0 or more non-`"` characters (`[^"]*`) and then everything else. The whole thing is replaced with the captured pattern.

You can also leave the pattern matching to `perl`:

```
perl -ne 's/.*CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="([^"]*).*/$1/ && print' /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic
```

Comment: I knew you would join at some point :P +1

Comment: then I would produce a python code..

Comment: `with open('/boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic') as f: for line in f: if line.startswith('CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG'): print line.split('"')[1]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj good stuff, care to post this please ? I've posted one with regex as well.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a combination of `grep` and `cut`, that does the same job.

```
$ grep "CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG" /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic | cut -d"\"" -f2                                                
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
```

Explanation:

- `grep "CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG" /boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic` is the part that finds the line, in the standard grep syntax:`grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]`. The output goes through pipe to the next stage
- `cut -d"\"" -f2`. This part uses cut to crop-off text separated by specific delimiter (which is specified  with `-d` flag). We have to escape the double quote with backslash so that shell allows taking double quote as one of the options to the `cut` command, rather than input to the shell itself. Now `cut` will treat output from `grep` as separated by `"` and split into three columns, `CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG`, `arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig`, and empty space. The line we need is the second column, that means we need to use `-f2` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Since I am currently learning `python` here is a version using exactly that.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

reg = re.compile('CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG')

with open("/boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic") as file :
   for line in file:
       if reg.match(line):
           print line.split('"')[1]
```

Sample run:

```
DIR:/TECH-BOOKS
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./extractString.py                                           
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig

DIR:/TECH-BOOKS
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat ./extractString.py                                       
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

reg = re.compile('CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG')

with open("/boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic") as file :
   for line in file:
       if reg.match(line):
           print line.split('"')[1]
```

Comment: indentation is very7 very important in python..

Comment: You don't need to go for regexd, just use mine ie, `line.startswith` because `re.match` is much slower than `startswith`