# python 2.x beside 3.4

Tags: launcher, python3, python-2.7

From noob to all...

Is it possible to have py2.x beside 3.4, preferably with launcher icons for both? If not, how can I start py2 IDE from command line?

I prefer py3, but need py2 and it's modules for some projects.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. and not afraid of terminal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed by default, but not with any Python IDEs. For starters, install IDLE for both versions:

```
sudo apt-get install idle idle3
```

The icons for both will show up in the Dash, and when you run them, you right click on the icons to lock them to the launcher.

If you don't mind using a terminal, run `python2` and `python3` in a terminal and see the difference.

Comment: Yes, that worked and was excactly what I needed! Thank You,  Muru.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with 2.7 and 3.4, and 2.7 is technically default, with `/usr/bin/python` being a symlink to `/usr/bin/python2.7`

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ python
python     python2    python3    python3.4m 
python/    python2.7  python3.4  python3m

skolodya@ubuntu:$ ls -l $(which python)                                        
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 15 00:39 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*
```

Ubuntu by default doesn't come with python IDE. It is sufficient to open any text editor, write code with the very very first line saying `#! /usr/bin/env python`, making the file executable , and running it. This is useful for learning a language and doing stuff that doesn't require anything super fancy to debug

Example from what I [answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/724054/295286) yesterday: 1) open vi text editor, write the code; 2) exit, make the file executable with `chmod +x filename` and 3) run it.

```
DIR:/python
skolodya@ubuntu:$ vi extractString.py                                          

DIR:/python
skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat extractString.py                                         
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

reg = re.compile('CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG')

with open("/boot/config-3.19.0-32-generic") as file :
   for line in file:
       if reg.match(line):
      print line.split('"')[1]




DIR:/python
skolodya@ubuntu:$ chmod +x extractString.py                                    

DIR:/python
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./extractString.py                                           
arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig
```